# Cómo hacer que se seleccione la ruta de salida en pdfkit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

tengo este código para crear un pdf a partir de una plantilla html usando pdfkit y jinja2. El problema es que no consigo hacer que el programa me pregunte donde crear el pdf y cómo llamarlo, así cómo un "guardar cómo" (valga la redundancia). Intenté usar el método: `output_path=os.getcwd()` pero me arroja error, tengo que especificar el nombre del pdf y lo crea en la carpeta donde está el código fuente. Si alguien sabe cómo resolverlo, gracias.

```
environment= Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("I:\Fase 2\plantilla\plantillas html"))
template=environment.get_template("plantilla-sencilla-entrada.html")
variables={"variable_empresa":"",
           "subtitulo":"",
           "tiempo":"",
           "ticket":"",
           "placa":"",
           "producto":"",
           "conductor":"", 
           "cedula":"", 
           "peso_g":"", 
           "num_g":"", 
           "peso_b":"",
           "peso_t":"", 
           "peso_n":"", 
           "peso_d":"", 
           "transporte":"", 
           "proveedor":""  
           ,"observaciones":""
           ,"variable_fecha_hora":""  }

#Base de datos
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute('SELECT * FROM ticket ORDER BY "column" DESC LIMIT 1')
resultado=cursor1.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
for registro in resultado:
    variables["variable_empresa"]="Empresa Demostración"
    variables["ticket"]=registro[0]
    variables["placa"]=registro[1]
    variables["producto"]=registro[4]
    variables["conductor"]=registro[2]
    variables["cedula"]=registro[3]
    variables["peso_g"]=registro[6]
    variables["num_g"]=registro[5]
    variables["peso_b"]=registro[14]
    variables["peso_t"]=registro[15]
    variables["peso_n"]=registro[16]
    variables["peso_d"]=registro[17]
    variables["transporte"]=registro[10]
    variables["proveedor"]=registro[9]
    variables["observaciones"]=registro[13]
    variables["variable_fecha_hora"]=(registro[11], registro[12])


#ruta_salida=tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename() 
html= template.render(variables)
options={'page-size':'Letter', 'margin-top':'0.05in', 'margin-right':'0.05in', 'margin-bottom':'0.05in', 'margin-left':'0.05in', 'encoding':'UTF-8'}
pdfkit.from_string(html, "prueba6.pdf", options=options)
```

Comment: Lo que buscas es [tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename). filedialog es un submodulo de tkinter, por lo que tendrás que importarlo con, por ejemplo, from tkinter import filedialog. Esta función "pausa" la ejecución sin trabar la interfaz y devuelve el directorio completo del archivo (incluyendo el nombre de archivo y la extensión)

Comment: Listo @DanteS. funcionó, gracias.

Comment: De nada compañero!

Comment: Por cierto @DanteS. , conoces alguna herramienta que convierta documentos word a html? Creé las plantillas en un convertidor online y no es muy bueno, las fuentes y las alineaciones no son las mejores. Creé las plantillas perfectas en word pero ninguna herramienta que he encontrado online puede convertir bien los cuadros de texto.

Comment: Lamentablemente, html no he tocado nunca, así que no conozco nada. Suerte de todas formas!

Comment: No problem brother